# How to stick item at bottom in LazyColumn jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I want to put items at **bottom** of `LazyColumn`. So what is the best recommended way of doing in `LazyColumn`. Some content I put in `item` or `itemIndexed` which is correctly, but unable to know how to stick in bottom of screen?

```
        LazyColumn(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(
                horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 16.dp)
            ),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        ) {
            item { Header() }

            itemsIndexed(storedDevice) { index, item ->
                Label({ index }, item, { list.size })
            }
            
            item { 
                Button() // stick in bottom of screen 
                Button() // stick in bottom of screen 
            }
        }
```

**Expected Outout**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move the `Button` outside the `LazyColumn`, using a `Column`
and applying the `weight` modifier to the `LazyColumn`.

Something like:

```
Column() {

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(
            horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    ) {

        items(itemsList) {
            Text("Item $it")
        }
    }

    //Footer
    Column() {
        Button(onClick={}){ Text("Button") } // stick in bottom of screen
        Button(onClick={}){ Text("Button") } // stick in bottom of screen
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if I have a Text with dynamic size.